# O App que fiz cancela o som de outros apps

Tags: android, react-native

Fiz um app para android, que em resumo é um feed de videos e imagens. Quando abro meu app e algum video é pausado ou executado, o som dos outros aplicativos também é pausado (Música, rádio). Já procurei algumas soluções: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/152 mas nenhuma das soluções que achei conseguiu resolver meu problema.

Meu `package.json`.

Existe algo na configuração do android que posso resolver isto, como bloquear as restrições do aplicativo de pausar aps terceiros?

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.23.1",
    "react-native-img-cache": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-inviewport": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-platform-touchable": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.5",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.4.0",
    "react-native-timeago": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-video-player": "^0.10.0",
    "react-navigation": "2.18.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
    "slugify": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.3.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-jest": "24.4.0",
    "jest": "24.4.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "assets/fonts/BalooTammudu"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo como resolver meu problema, mas não acho que é uma solução 100% eficaz. Eu reli o post do github da pergunta e aparentemente o props `disableFocus` não funciona, o valor default da variavel está voltando. Não sei quão longe isso vai, mas ao comentar essa função no arquivo `ReactExoplayerView.java` e sempre retornar `true` desabilita o focus dos videos. Porém acredito que todos os vídeos do App ficarão sem focus.

```
private boolean requestAudioFocus() {
    // if (disableFocus) {
    //     return true;
    // }
    // int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this,
    //         AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    //         AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    // return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED;
    return true;
}
```